# how to use $ character as an end of line character in [] set definition?

Tags: java, regex

`pattern1` does what I want. It splits text separated with dot. I tried to use `pattern` for the same purpose but `$` seems to be representing $ rather than end of input. any suggestions to make it work?

```
    String pattern1 = "(\\w+)(?:\\.|$)";
    String pattern = "(\\w+)[\\.$]";
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher("name.surname.value1.value");
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `.split()` instead?

Comment: `$` should be at the end of your pattern instead of being inside the `)`.

Comment: Except for `-`and `^` (and maybe 1-2 others) at the beginning of a bracket `[]`, any sign within brackets `[]` is taken literally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$` is represented as literal when used in character class..

There's no way you could use it to represent end of string/line in character class.

Use it in group as you used in your 1st pattern

Answer (score 3):

> I tried to use pattern for the same purpose but $ seems to be representing $ rather than end of input.

Because, you've used `$` inside `[]` as a member of a regex *character class*. Hence, it loses its meaning as an *end-of-line* anchor and starts getting matched literally.

Also note that if you're trying to match sentences ending with a dot; using `\w` alone won't help as it doesn't cover spaces.

Answer (score 0):

"." is a meta-character that will match any character except newline.

Check this [link](http://ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-1/) for details (section 1.3).